# Magento PIM integration, how best to handle attribute set

Tags: magento-1.9, import, product-import

Having to import products from a PIM solution and seeking recommendation on the best way to handle attribute_set. Would this typically be mastered in PIM and extracted or is there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the PIM solution. In Bluestone PIM, the Mangento integration pulls all attributes from Bluestone PIM into **one attribute set** in Magento (called 'Bluestone PIM Attribute Set'). This makes it easy and well-organised for grouping all attributes from Bluestone PIM into just one attribute set.

Please note that this will not work if a user has multiple attribute groups (separate groups used for different purposes such as *Marketing information*, *Logistics information*, *Care information* etc), and wants them to be synced in to the different groups in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Readme
Pimcore 5 & 6 Module Magento 2 Integration
This module is a part (1/2) of the Pimcore - Magento connector. It allows for the integration of your Pimcore platform with the Magento 2 e-commerce platform, including synchronization of products, categories and assets.

Description
This plugin allows Pimcore to send all data about products and categories to remote eCommerce systems.

Compatibility
This module is compatible with Pimcore >= 5.4 and Pimcore 6.0.

Installing/Getting started
Open your Pimcore
Install Pimcore 5 Module Magento 2 Integration via composer composer require divante-ltd/pimcore-magento2-bridge
Enable bundle by running bin/console pimcore:bundle:enable DivanteMagentoIntegrationBundle
Clear cache by running bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup
Install Bundle by running bin/console pimcore:bundle:install DivanteMagentoIntegrationBundle
Reload Pimcore
Create a new object of class IntegrationConfiguration

Find a guide for Pimcore beginners here <-- https://factory.dev/pimcore-knowledge-base/how-to/pimcore-for-beginners